# Loop through all cells in every open workbook and worksheet and get comment

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to extract all title fields from a set of workbooks and worksheets along with their comments. I'm trying to find all cells that are locked, not empty, and not calculated. I've put this code together but it throws an error on the `cell.comment.text` line. It comes back with the error:

`Run-time error '91':
Object Variable or With block variable not set`

```
Sub extract()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Dim Db As Worksheet
Dim NoRow As Integer: Dim i As Integer: Dim j As Integer
Dim cell

'   On Error GoTo extract_Error
Set Db = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
    If Not WB.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        For Each ws In WB.Sheets
            i = Db.Cells(Db.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
                If cell.Locked = True And IsEmpty(cell) = False And cell.HasFormula = False Then
                    i = i + 1
                    Db.Cells(i, 1) = WB.Name
                    Db.Cells(i, 2) = ws.Name
                    Db.Cells(i, 3) = cell.Value
                    Db.Cells(i, 4) = cell.Comment.Text
                End If
            Next cell
        Next ws
    End If
Next WB

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

extract_Error:

MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure extract of Module Module1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `Cell.Comment` can be null, put an `On Error Resume Next` in front of it if you want to skip any errors thrown, you can always put `On Error GoTo 0` to have other errors thrown:

```
For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
   If Not WB.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
       For Each ws In WB.Sheets
           i = Db.Cells(Db.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
           For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
               If cell.Locked = True And IsEmpty(cell) = False And cell.HasFormula = False Then
                   i = i + 1
                   Db.Cells(i, 1) = WB.Name
                   Db.Cells(i, 2) = ws.Name
                   Db.Cells(i, 3) = cell.Value
                   On Error Resume Next
                   Db.Cells(i, 4) = cell.Comment.Text
                   On Error GoTo 0
               End If
           Next cell
       Next ws
   End If
Next WB
```

If you want to catch and print the error, do something like this:

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
    a = 5 / 0
    If Err.Number > 1 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: As suggested by @CmPi - letting an exception bubble up may be slower than actually testing for the case in advance:

```
If Not cell.Comments Is Nothing Then
  Db.Cells(i, 4) = cell.Comment.Text
End If
```

Comment: Have tried that. It runs but doesn't extract the comments

Comment: and `Db.Cells(i, 4)` is not null? What does `Debug.Print cell.Comment.Text` return?

Comment: I just tested by adding a comment (`SHIFT`+`F2`) to a cell and dropping to Immediate window `?Range("A1").Comment.Text` works fine...

Comment: That worked thanks. Don't know what was creating the issue earlier. I've got error handling at the bottom of my code. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just test it before :

```
If Not cell.Comment Is Nothing Then Db.Cells(i, 4) = cell.Comment.Text
```

Comment: this is better :o my solution is sloppy

Answer (score 0):

I'm on linux machine at the moment and cannot try the code but have you tried converting the cell.comment.text to a string, therefore even if it's empty it should return an empty string value

```
Db.Cells(i, 4) = CStr(cell.Comment.Text)
```

As it stands your code will return empty comments also if this is not intended then you'll need to add

```
if CStr(cell.comment.text) <> "" then
    Db.Cells(i, 4) = CStr(cell.Comment.Text)
end if
```